# new gradle format confusion and migrating causes Could not find method testCompile()

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, spotless

I have a build.gradle with

```
plugins {
   id {some plugin for all projects}
   id "com.diffplug.spotless" version "5.1.1"
}
```

AND THEN I have an allprojects {} section that defines ONE apply plugin: 'jacoco' and a subprojects {} section that declares apply plugin: 'java' with a few others

Immediately adding spotless messed with stuff and errors out that it cannot find the java plugin so then I modify ALL plugins to be in the plugins section like so

```
plugins {
   id "java"
   id "checkstyle"
   id "eclipse"
   id "idea"
   id "jacoco"
   id "com.diffplug.spotless" version "5.1.1"
   id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.5" //This prints out a task tree (pretty print)
}
```

This then results in this error

```
Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [junit:junit:4.11] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

So for some reason the java plugin is lost.  I can't figure out the right combination here to migrate everything to this new plugins section format.

How do I do that?  I randomly tried putting a plugins section in allprojects and subprojects but that results in this new error

```
Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_d8c2jgy4ua1m0vkv9kmvgefmc$_run_closure2$_closure5@62337fda] on root project 'providersvc-all' of type org.gradle.api.Project
```

How does this new plugins section work?   I can't seem to migrate without it breaking everything.  I just want java plugin, testCompile, and spotless to play nicely together right now

EDIT(forgot to attach the full trimmed down file that does not work):

```
plugins {
   id "java"
   id "com.diffplug.spotless" version "5.1.1"
}

ext {
    //dependency versions every project usees so we version in one location all jars(less jar hell this way)
    deps = [
       'junit':           'junit:junit:4.11'
    ]
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
       maven {
           //webpieces VERSIONED snapshots so you can lock on a snapshot
          url "https://dl.bintray.com/deanhiller/maven"
       }

       //For testing locally
       maven {
         url uri('/tmp/myRepo/')
       }
   }
}

subprojects {
   dependencies {
       testCompile deps['junit']
   }
}
```

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

You are only applying the plugins to the root project - not the sub-projects. However, if you like to configure plugins through the `subprojects` configuration, you have to use the `apply plugin` syntax. But you don't have to use the old `buildscript` block for configuring the classpath and repositories if you a combination of the two.

Here is an example. I am assuming the root project is not a Java project. I have also removed your comments and inserted mine instead for the sole reason to make them easier to spot.

```
plugins {
   id "com.diffplug.spotless" version "5.1.1" apply false // <-- Set "apply false" here
   // This makes it configure which version to use on the classpath for the entire build, but without applying it.
   // Notice that the Java plugin is not specified here anymore.
   // This is because it is a core plugin so you can't set the version (and I am assuming you don't want it on in the root project).
}

ext {
    deps = [
       'junit':           'junit:junit:4.11'
    ]
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral() // <-- You can remove this if you want as it is already present as a proxy in jcenter().
       maven {
          url "https://dl.bintray.com/deanhiller/maven"
       }

       maven {
         url uri('/tmp/myRepo/')
       }
   }
}

subprojects {
   // Here are the two plugins
   apply plugin: "java"
   apply plugin: "com.diffplug.spotless"

   dependencies {
       testImplementation deps['junit'] // <-- testCompile renamed to testImplementation as the former has been deprecated for a long time
   }
}
```

Comment: ohhhhhh @BjornVester I had id 'java' apply false so I thought that way was not even working.  I didn't realize plugins could be so inconsistent there in that you can't do that with java.  I never tried without id 'java' in the plugins section.  I thought everything was moving towards the new plugins {...} section so I am really confused, but oh well.....going to try that out tonight.

Comment: Also, I don't really want any plugins in the root project by the way but I thought this new plugins section is the way things are supposed to be going in the future for loading speed.  I am so confused as to the correct direction now vs. the old apply plugin way.